# Database design advice (specific example- Fantasy Football)

Tags: database-design

I have a database for a fantasy football competition.
There are three schemas:

- afl (relating to the Australian Football League entities)
- ddhp (relating to the local fantasy competition entities) and
- dbo (for entities not specifically owned by either).

Description of Entities

- Each player plays for an AFL Team (there's no need to track this by time, so I just record the current team the player plays for, and update this if the player changes clubs).
- Some players play for a ddhp Team. This is expressed by a Contract which has a FromRound and a ToRound, expressing the time boundaries for which the contract is valid.
- There are Rounds. There's basically no difference between an afl and a ddhp round, so there's just one table.
- There are Fixtures, which represent two ddhp teams playing against each other in a round.
- When a player plays in a round, they record Stats.
- Each round, each ddhp Team selects from their contracted players those who will play for them that round. This is represented by RoundPlayers.

The problem is that there's a level of awkwardness between RoundPlayers and Stats. Logically, a RoundPlayer has a row in Stats to represent their playing in that round (if they played). This is a one-to-one relationship, but both tables are optional. A Player might not play in a round and therefore have no Stats. A player might not also be selected as a RoundPlayer and therefore have no row in that table. One is keyed by Round and PlayerId and the other by Round and ContractId. Navigating from one to the other is a bit awkward, especially when trying to use an ORM (eg Entity Framework 4) as the navigation properties are based on Foreign Keys, while this relationship goes via an intermediate table (Contract) to get the PlayerId.

I've thought about adding the ContractId to Stats (if a player was chosen to play that round) but that felt wrong. I also thought about removing the 1-to-1 relationship between Stat and Roundplayer and moving them to a single table, but this felt wrong also.

I'd appreciate any thoughts as to how to get a better relationship between RoundPlayer and Stat or even any ideas which might change this structure entirely.

[image]

Comment: Please write the minimum necessary to ask 1 specific question re 1 specific place you are stuck including code for design choices. PS "Feels wrong" is not helpful. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

The main problem you have is navigation, due to `Record ID` based data model.

> [d] The problem is that there's a level of awkwardness between RoundPlayers and Stats.
> [e] One is keyed by Round and PlayerId and the other by Round and ContractId. Navigating from one to the other is a bit awkward.

This thread is old, but it has no answers, and you said:

> I'd appreciate any thoughts as to how to get a better relationship between RoundPlayer and Stat or even any ideas which might change this structure entirely.

You've got a lot more problems than just that one: most of your query code will be horrendous.   Those difficulties [d][e] are typical of the kind of issue that results from a `Record ID` based model.  You already know your navigation and query code is difficult, so I am not telling you anything that you do not know.  You have implemented a model that is common practice, from textbooks and posts that are heavily promoted and marketed as "relational", and it is not actually correct.

## The Relational Model

The ***Relational Model*** by Dr E F Codd is specifically designed to prevent all such issues, and to make queries straight-forward.  It has a foundation in Logic ("math" is the expression of that Logic), First Order Predicate Calculus (aka First Order Logic), and therefore it has a scientifically robust foundation.

The benefits of the *RM* are realised only when the whole *RM* (not fragments) is understood, and applied.

The authoritative source documents are **only**:

- Codd's **[Relational Model](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf)** 1970
- Codd's **[Twelve Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules#cite_ref-2)** 1985
- Note that Codd is not "a pioneer of the Relational Model", he is **the one and only inventor**.  This view attempts to position the detractors as "other pioneers".  It was not a wagon train, it was a lone ranger.
- Note that no academic papers have been written to articulate, or extend, or progress, the *RM*.  For 50 and 35 years respectively.  The Relational Model stands alone.
- SQL is today's rendition of Codd's *RM* and his Relational Algebra.  Beware the databases that inaccurately use the name.
- IDEF1X is the Standard (both Methodology and Notation) for modelling data Relationally.  Available since 1985, NIST Standard since 1993.

All other papers (even those by Codd, which have a specific purpose that is related to the specific audience and purpose) and textbooks are written by the detractors.  Sadly, the professors and lecturers follow them, without even referencing the *RM*, as they should.

### 1960's Record Filing Systems • Anti-Relational Muddle

While RFS (in either the Hierarchical or Network DBMS of the day, or plain old ISAM files) was perfectly normal before 1984 (Codd's paper was June 1970 but it took over a decade for the platform suppliers to switch over to Relational), after 1984, it is an absurd relic of a bygone era.

The stuff that is heavily promoted and marketed by C J Date; Hugh Darwen; Ronald Fagin; et al, **as** "relational" retains the 1960's paradigm of physical pointers, plus a couple of fragments from the *RM*.  Of course, it is a mess, so over the five decades, in an attempt to formalise the mess, they have come up with various abnormal "normal forms".  The definitions for which keep changing.  More, later.

In case it needs to be said, the RFS marketed as "relational" has no foundation; no logic; no "math" behind it (sure, it has "math" to support the 17 ever-changing abnormal "normal forms" that deal with fragments of the Relational Key, that are not in the *RM*).  It is not a *model*.

### The Difference

The *RM* does not use physical pointers to records, such as `id; Record ID; GUID`; etc.  In fact, that is expressly prohibited, because that is precisely what pre-Relational, 1960's Record Filing Systems used, that was the well-known great obstacle, that Codd was tasked to overcome.

One great *visible* difference (there are many visible differences, one cannot be singled out and held out as *the greatest*), is:

- whereas pre-Relational systems used physical pointers (`Record ID`, etc) as references throughout the system, to link a set of child *records* to a parent *record*,
- the *RM* demands that logical *rows* (as opposed to physical *records*) are identified (uniqueness) by a Relational Key, which is "made up from the data",
- and the references between child *rows* and the parent *rows* are by those logical Relational Keys

Even in the pre-Relational systems, we had genuine logical Keys (ISAM in the DBMS or plain old ISAM), the pointers were for chasing the linked records in other files

- but in the current paradigm, 1960's Record Filing Systems promoted as "relational", the physical pointer`Record ID` is implemented as *the* "primary key", eliminating the logical Keys altogether.
- eventually you find out that you have duplicate *rows* (as opposed to *records*), you have to determine the real Key, and add an index for it to prevent duplicate rows.

The Hierarchical and Network DBMS of the 1960's; 70's; and 80's had Referential Integrity, albeit via physical pointers, because they were declared, and the DBMS enforce it.

- In the current Anti-Relational paradigm, there is not even that (sure, a non-key is declared as "primary key", and "foreign keys" may well be declared, but that is physical, not over the logical data.
- Thus the data that *can* have Referential Integrity, does not have it.
- Thus the RFS marketed as "relational" is truly 1960's RFS, before DBMS were supplied, hence my determination of the category.

### Data Duplication

The enormity of this difference, the benefits, cannot be explained here (out of scope). One great value that is relevant here, is ease of access and ease of query.

- Assuming that you know to avoid duplicate data *rows* (as opposed to duplicate `Record IDs`), you will have an unique index on each logical Key
- That means that each `Record ID` field in each file is **one additional column and one additional index** more than the equivalent Relational table
- If you do not know, that means you have duplicate logical rows (when you use `SELECT` for report, you are seeking logically related data, but it is stored in a physical frame that denies that logical related-ness) all over the shore, and do not know it yet.

### Truth

One quality about truth is, it is permanent, it never changes (if it changes, it cannot be truth.)  The *RM* has not changed since June 1970.  It is so reliable that several major platform providers have produced complete platforms that implement it.  It has become the dominant database design method (despite the fact that it has been substituted with a primitive paradigm).

### Logic

The great difference (this one is invisible, it is enormous) between 1960's RFS and the *RM*, is:

- **the *RM* is entirely Logical**

In all aspects.  One aspect, the Logical foundation, has been identified above, here is another.  If you understand Logic as pure theory, and as applied in any applied science, (pure theory is useless unless it has an application), you will understand that:

- there is nothing in the universe that cannot be expressed *precisely* in terms of FOPC
- therefore, there is nothing in the universe that cannot be expressed *precisely* in terms of the *Relational Model*, which is founded on FOPC.  This means all constraints are logical (declarations, not code).

The corollary is important: without this Logic::FOPC::RM::Data Model understanding

- problems that are difficult to model,
- and certainly all modelling nuances,

would be impossible. And queries on that non-Relational definition of a database (falsely labelled "relational") would be horrendous.

### Predicate

The ultimate understanding of this subject is that the database is defined *in toto* by declarations.  These are FOPC **Predicates**, the **P** in FOPC, because the "theoreticians" are oblivious to this subject.

All Predicates are visible in an [IDEF1X](https://www.iso.org/standard/60614.html) data model, they can also be expressed in text form.  SQL/DDL is a subset of those Predicates, with the others being implied.

In other words, the end result, a data model designed by one who understands all the above, is in fact a **Logic Map**, it is truly *Semantic*.  And not at all if one is ignorant of the Logical properties of the *RM*, or if one rebels against it as the "theoreticians" do.  They do not even understand what *semantic* means, they cannot read a graphical data model.

### SQL

Codd defined a data sub-language for his *RM*, it is the articulation of that Logic (via his *Relational Algebra*).  It is entirely logical, it is the programmatic articulation of the *RM*.  The implementation of that is what we know today as SQL.  IBM had System/R and proprietary SQL for a full decade, before they were forced to publish it, it then became a Standard.

- Referencing my earlier point re FOPC and the RM, that there is nothing in the universe that cannot be defined *precisely* in it:
- since SQL is Logical and Relational, therefore there is no query that cannot be serviced simply and directly (straight-forward Logic) in a genuine Relational database.
- Therefore it is a simple and absolute truth, that
- in the event that SQL queries are difficult, the database is not Relational, not Logical
- Over the decades, I have converted about 40 rather large and difficult databases, from RFS falsely labelled as "relational", to genuine Relational, Logical.  The result is the same: all reports serviced by a single `SELECT`, which is easy to code.  Not to mention the incomparable speed.
- or else, if the database is indeed Relational, then the SQL coder is simply ignorant
- Often I have to educate the coder, because they are so enslaved by the complex SQL demanded for the RFSs that they are used to, they do not see the simplicity of the navigation in a Relational database.
- The corollary is important.  If you have a non-logical database, an RFS badged as "relational", each file a physical frame that contains *records*, not logical *rows*, SQL is simply not designed for that, and thus the navigation and queries will be, quite predictably, difficult.  That, is what you are suffering.
- Beware: the freeware is not SQL compliant; they have no ACID Transactions; no Server Architecture, therefore their use of the term SQL is arguably incorrect.  Lots of extras, but not the basics.

---

## Solution

> The problem still exists though it's mitigated via other methods.

With a genuine Relational data model, first you will not have such problems.  Second, you will not need to mitigate any problems outside the database (eg. middleware or code segments all over the place).

- By definition, the database is a single recovery unit.  It must be self-contained, self-constrained,  and self-describing.
- That means all constraints; all Transactions must be in the database, not in app code, not in middleware.

### Relational Data Model

Since you obviously have a fair amount of experience, let me just give you the solution, without an introductory explanation.  Please ask specific questions: we can perfect the model, and complete the question.

[image: SimonTA]

#### Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.iso.org/standard/60614.html)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993.
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for those who are new to the *Relational Model*, or its modelling method.  Note that IDEF1X models are rich in detail and precision, showing all required details, whereas home-grown models, being unaware of the imperatives of the Standard, have far less than that.  Which means, the notation needs to be understood.

### Content • General

- That is too wide for an Inline Graphic, you may prefer the **[PDF](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Simon/Simon%20TA.pdf)** in A3 (or 11x17).
- I have provided a bit more detail, such as the **Predicates** explained above in text form.  Please check them carefully.
- Since you have the data in an RFS and you use SQL, populating a new test database, each table with a few thousand rows, should be easy:

  ```sql
  INSERT New_Table ... 
      SELECT DISTINCT Logical_Rows
          FROM RFS_File ...`
          WHERE New_Table_Conditions ...
  ```

That is the best way to experience the ease of access and ease of query.  Specific SQL code is given below.

#### Method

I have executed two tasks:

- first, modelling the data, compliant with the ***Relational Model***, and
- second, Normalising the data.  That results in complete elimination of duplicate data; Update Anomalies; and Nulls.

You now have Relational facilities and features that the RFS does not, cannot, have:

- **Relational Integrity**
  Eg. Stats for Round::Pick::Player are constrained to a RoundPlayer (not to just any Player)
- **Relational Power**
  Minimal JOINs (eg. see code for TeamStats);
  Any report satisfied by a single SELECT;
  easy navigation; straight-forward query code

> I've thought about adding the ContractId to Stats (if a player was chosen to play that round) but that felt wrong

Yes.  That is exactly the type of fiddling that one is forced to do, in order to "improve" an RFS, to make it work.  In so doing, one duplicates data and creates an Update Anomaly.  That is one of the many things that one never has to do with a Relational data model.

- **Relational Speed**
  Minimal indices; fastest DML; smallest packets (wrt cache memory & network)

### Content • Specific

- **Assumption**: that the logical, natural Key for Round is ( Year, Round ), not ( Round ).  Otherwise it is limited to 1 year.
- **Assumption**: that PlayerStats are relevant (collected) for RoundPlayers, not TeamPlayers, not RoundPicks.
- PlayerStats is given in Isolated Descriptor NF (tighter than "6NF"): this allows pivoting on ***any*** two Dimensions, etc.
- Statistics for {Year, Round, Team [Coach], Player [TeamAFL] } are now simple.
- When a Player is contracted to a Team, he is a TeamPlayer.  Contract equals TeamPlayer.  The Fact of a Contract, and the Fact of a TeamPlayer, is one and the same Fact.
- **Assumption**: that a contract (FromRound; ToRound) is for one year.  Otherwise TeamPlayer needs FromYear; ToYear
- Constraining RoundPicks to a contracted Round requires a `CONSTRAINT`  that calls a `Function` (Standard SQL, code given in the PDF).
- Player & Coach details have been Normalised into Person: the international convention for Person Identity has been implemented
- Surrogates are prohibited in the RM.  It breaks the **Access Path Independence Rule**.
- PersonId is the only surrogate retained, it is justified because the otherwise PK is too long for migration as an FK.
- Nevertheless, it remains a Relational breach: it cuts off the reference-ability from the descendant rows (eg. RoundPlayer.PlayerId) to all tables above the breach (ancestor rows, eg. PersonBirthPlace.BirthCountry).
- NULL is an indicator that Normalisation is incomplete.  Nulls have been eliminated via Normalisation of the Nullable columns:
- PersonBirthDate
  PersonBirthPlace
  DraftPick
  Draft
  (the Alternative, with NULL columns, is given in the PDF)
- RoundPlayer
  Eliminates the difficulty determining a RoundPick who has played, but has no PlayerStats
- PlayerStats
  Additionally, now that it is IDNF, none of the Stats columns are Null.
- Red columns are simply those that could not be read from the original PNG.  Such are, of course, unknown, and thus excluded from the exercise.

### The Difference

Of course, I had to study the RFS, your PNG, in order to determine what it does, so that I could produce a Relational data model.  No surprise, I drew an [IDEF1X](https://www.iso.org/standard/60614.html) model.  I realised later that it may be useful to you: perhaps to understand the existing RFS better (ie. in Relational terms); perhaps to understand what the difference between that and the given Relational data model.  The **[RFS PDF](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Simon/Simon%20RFS.pdf)**.

### SQL Code

This demonstrates one aspect of **Relational Power**: the power of Relational Keys, specifically `JOIN` Power.  Although a Relational database may have more tables, it actually requires less `JOINs` than the equivalent RFS.  Eg. where the `SELECT JOINs` two distal tables, intermediate files (in the otherwise RFS) do not have to be `JOINed`.

#### Team Stats

```
SELECT  Year,
        Team.Team, -- ShortName
        Coach = LastName + "," + FirstName,
        SUM( Value )
    FROM Team
         JOIN PlayerStats ON Team.Team = PlayerStats.Team
         JOIN Person      ON Team.CoachId = Person.PersonId,
         ( SELECT DISTINCT  Year
               FROM Round ) Year
    WHERE Metric = "Goal" 
        AND SUM( Value ) NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Year, Team, Coach
```

#### TeamAFL Stats for One Year

```
SELECT  TeamAFL.TeamAFL, -- ShortName
        Player = LastName + "," + FirstName,
        SUM( Value )
    FROM TeamAFL
        JOIN Player      ON TeamAFL.TeamAFL = Player.TeamAFL
        JOIN PlayerStats ON Player.PlayerId = PlayerStats.PlayerId
        JOIN Person      ON Player.PlayerId = Person.PersonId
    WHERE Year = "2017" 
        AND Metric = "Goal"
    GROUP BY Team, Player
```

Comment: This looks like a very good answer. While editing I notice that "FOPC" was referred to but not introduced - should the reader know that, or would it be worth defining it (either with a hyperlink or a description)?

Comment: As an aside, I am intrigued by the academic disagreement about database design that you have referred to in some of your answers. Out of curiosity, are there any independent discussions about this? I tried [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Date+Darwen+Fagin+Codd&ia=web) and could only find a [newsgroup discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.theory/zeLvM4sQPGg) that you were leading. I don't claim to be well-read on this, and wouldn't mind a "referee" walk-through from a third-party - is this a big discussion in the database theory community?

Answer (score 0):

The flaw, it seems to me, and I think you're seeing the same thing, is that you have two tables whose records directly relate to each other, and yet they have totally different keys.

As I understand your description, if there is a RoundPlayers record there will always be exactly one matching Stats record, and vice versa. In that case, I think the textbook answer is:

(a) Combine the two into a single record. They always go together, why not make them one record? The main reason I see NOT to do this is that perhaps a RoundPlayer is interesting in different contexts than a Stats. That is, a RoundPlayer is interesting when we're scheduling, but a Stats is interesting for long-term accumulation of player performance.

Or (b) Throw away the foreign keys in Stats to Team, Player, and Rounds. Instead give it a single foreign key to RoundPlayer, or perhaps duplicate the links to Contract and Round. That would make your keys consistent.

The link to Team seems particularly suspicious to me. Could you not find the Team via the Player? If the Player switches to another Team, should the Team in Stats be updated to match? If so, it's redundant and creates the possibility of the two getting out of sync. Or does the Stat remain tied to the original Team? But what difference does the Team make anyway, as that's an AFL Team and not a DDHP Team? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding a requirement. I know nothing about Australian football. (It must be a very difficult game, as the players must all compete while hanging upside down from the bottom of the world ...)

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm happy to have comments, even late ones. The problem still exists though it's mitigated via other methods. (a) doens't work as RoundPlayers exist before Stats do. They are created at different times. Also not all Stats have a RoundPlayer. (b) doesn't work as not all Stats have a RoundPlayer. I see that I wasn't clear in my question when I said there was a 1-to-1 relationship, will edit later :)